# Holoviews html output graph to Medium article

Tags: python, plotly, holoviews

Does anyone know of a way to embed a html graph created with Holoviews in a Medium article?

One of my ideas was to convert the Holoviews object to Plotly and then add/upload that object to my chart studio profile. After that I would be able embed that Plotly chart in Medium. But I am not being able to convert the Holoviews object to Plotly format.

Any ideas?

Thank you a lot!

Vasco

Comment: To clarify, are you using the Plotly backend within HoloViews? If so, you should be able to get a Plotly figure back (no longer anything to do with HoloViews) by doing `fig = hv.render(obj, backend='plotly')`. No idea whether that's enough for Medium, though!

Comment: No, I am using the Bokeh backend with HoloViews.
That's why it becomes harder. Do you know an easy way to convert from Bokeh to Plotly backend without having to change the entire code?